# Clipboard failure in tmux + vim after upgrading to MacOS Sierra

Tags: vim, tmux, macos-sierra, neovim

Yesterday, I upgraded to MacOS Sierra and it broke my clipboard functionality in my tmux + neovim setup.

Here is the behavior:

- I can use the standard ctrl+c, ctrl+p to copy/paste between system <-> vim
- I can yank/paste between two VIM instances when NOT in a tmux session
- I cannot yank/paste between two VIM instances when in a tmux session

Whenever I use the clipboard in vim within a tmux session, I get the following vim error:

```
clipboard: error:
```

My `.vimrc` is huge, but here's what I think might be relevant:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

In my `.tmux.conf` (also truncated for brevity):

```
set -g prefix `                                   # use tilde key as prefix
bind ` send-key `                                 # insert tilde by pressing twice

set -g history-limit 100000                       # set buffer size
set -s escape-time 0                              # fix escape key in vim
set -g allow-rename off                           # keep window names static
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"         # set the TERM to 256 colors
set -g base-index 1                               # start window count at 1
set -g pane-base-index 1                          # start pane count at 1
set -g default-shell $SHELL                       # use zsh as shell
```

**EDIT**: This appears to be related to the bug reported here:

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/543

https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/53

Comment: Neovim or Vim ?

Comment: @romainl Both, so long as they are running in a tmux session. See the repo mentioned in the 2nd issue link. Appears to be a recurring regression introduced with each new MacOS release.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This seem to be a regression on macOS Sierra. A solution that worked for me has been mentioned by [Josh McGinnis](https://github.com/joshuamcginnis) https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/543:

`brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`

Ensure the following is set in .tmux.conf:

```
set -g default-shell $SHELL 
set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l ${SHELL}"
```

In .vimrc or ~/.config/nvim/init.vim (for Neovim):

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Now all is well and I can copy/paste between system <-> vim sessions using vim keybindings and/or system ctrl+c / ctrl+p.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I held off upgrading for a while for little things like this that may occur.  Well, Apple annoyed me for the last time and I upgraded... DOH!

Comment: Thanks for this, worked for me.

I'm using the "*" register for copying to the clipboard, so I skipped the `set clipboard=unnamed` line.

Comment: This work. However, every new tmux pane that is opened is named `reattach-to-user-namespace`. Is this expected?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini I personally changed this fix a bit to avoid that issue. In my `~/.bashrc` (I use bash), I added `alias nvim='reattach-to-user-namespace -l nvim'`. That way, I'm only calling reattach-to-user-namespace when needed, since I don't copy and paste anywhere else in bash.

Comment: `set clipboard=unnamed` worked for me! Thanks! (I'm not even using tmux)

Comment: Remember to restart tmux server `tmux kill-server` after reloading `.tmux.conf` configuration.

Comment: Make sure you're using the Homebrew vim and not the system vim. `which vim` should print `/usr/local/bin/vim`, and `vim --version` should show that the `+clipboard` option is active. Installing Homebrew vim with the `--with-override-system-vi` option should set it up properly.

Answer (score 9):

Upgrading brew + vim + tmux fixed this for me:

```
brew update
brew upgrade vim
brew upgrade tmux
```

**Notes:**

- I am not using Neovim but hopefully this will help anyway
- This may take a while depending on how slow your machine is
- When I did this brew upgraded ruby for me and it complained that it wouldn't overwrite the existing symlinks so I had to manually run: `brew link --overwrite ruby`
- Tmux complained about the following setting after the upgrade. I just commented it out: `# set-option -g status-utf8 on`
- I had a warning about needing the new xcode tools so I ran the following and accepted the GUI prompts: `xcode-select --install` (In hindsight this may mess up my `react-native` install :/. Buyer beware)
- When first running `brew update` brew complained it didn't have write access to `/usr/local` so I made myself the owner of `/usr/local` **NON-RECURSIVE**. After the update brew told me I could change the owner back to `root:wheel`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you need to restart the tmux server with the following command:`tmux kill server`

Comment: for tmux and Iterm2 I needed to get a test release for this to work (go to iterm2 preferences | general and select `prompt for test releases` in the services section.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same upon upgrading to Sierra. In my case it stemmed from having the YankRing plugin installed.

Adding the following to my .vimrc fixed it for me:

```
"-------------------------------------------------------------
" Fix for YankRing bug
"-------------------------------------------------------------
let g:yankring_clipboard_monitor=0
```